# Passing user-defined types around in Cython

Tags: c++, python, oop, cython

Consider the following example C++ classes which I want to expose to Python via Cython. A `Producer` creates a `Product` which is passed to a `Consumer`.

```
class Product {
public:
    Product() : x(42) {
    }

    Product(int xin) : x(xin) {
    }

    int x;
};


class Producer {
public:
    Product create(int xin) {
        Product p(xin);
        return p;
    }
};

class Consumer {
public:
    void consume(Product p) {
        std::cout << p.x << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And here is the Python wrapper code in  a `*.pyx` file.

```
cdef extern from "CythonMinimal.h":
    cdef cppclass _Product "Product":
        _Product() except +
        _Product(int x) except +
        int x

cdef extern from "CythonMinimal.h":
    cdef cppclass _Producer "Producer":
        _Producer() except +
        _Product create(int x)

cdef extern from "CythonMinimal.h":
    cdef cppclass _Consumer "Consumer":
        _Consumer() except +
        void consume(_Product p)


cdef class Product:
    cdef _Product instance

    cdef setInstance(self, _Product instance):
        self.instance = instance

    def getX(self):
        return self.instance.x

cdef class Producer:
    cdef _Producer instance

    def create(self, x):
        p = Product()
        cdef _Product _p = self.instance.create(x)
        p.setInstance(_p)
        return p

cdef class Consumer:
    cdef _Consumer instance

    def consume(self, product):
        self.instance.consume(product.instance)
```

So I've managed to return my user-defined objects by using the `setInstance` method, but I cannot yet pass objects. The `Consumer.consume` method does not work:

```
cls ~ $ python3 setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
cythoning CythonMinimal.pyx to CythonMinimal.cpp

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef class Consumer:
    cdef _Consumer instance

    def consume(self, product):
        self.instance.consume(product.instance)
                              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

CythonMinimal.pyx:41:31: Cannot convert Python object to '_Product'
```

Can you suggest a fix for the `consume` method?

Comment: You should type the product argument, otherwise Cython can't know that it has C-level instance field: `def consume(self, Product product not None):`. As a bonus, Cython will automatically check that the passed value is actualy a `Product` instance and raise `TypeError` if necessary. `not None` clause will do similar check for None.

Comment: @NikitaNemkin  That's actually a full answer.